# How to rotate a rotation quaternion in the body frame to a rotation quaternion in the world frame?

Tags: rotation, frame

I have a sensor (3 axis gyroscope) which can rotate and measure angular velocity in 3 dimensions (aligned with the sensor).
I know what its current orientation is with respect to the world frame. Call this quaternion qs.
I take a reading from my gyroscope and integrate it to give me a rotation in the sensor frame. Call this quaternion qr.

I now want to apply the rotation qr to the current orientation qs to obtain the new orientation, qs'.
But I cannot use qr directly as it describes a rotation in the sensor body frame.

I need to transform my rotation quaternion into the world frame, and then I could just apply it to the orientation i.e. qs' = qs * qr_world.
But I am really struggling to understand how I can perform this transformation qr -> qr_world.

Does this even make sense? I wonder if I have fundamentally misunderstood some concepts here. If it does make sense, then I am specifically interested in understanding how to do this using quaternion operations (if that is possible) rather than rotation matrices or euler angles.

Comment: What are you confused about? The order of the multiplication?

Comment: The transformation of a rotation described in the sensor body frame to a rotation described in the world frame. I have edited my question to try and make this clearer.

Comment: This is actually simpler than you may think. Remember, `qs` and `qr` are fundamentally different, where the former represents orientation (in reference to the outside world) and the latter represents a mere rotation (without any external reference at all). You can think of `qr` as the delta to get to `qs'`. Therefore, there is no need for somehow further translating anything.

Comment: After additional reading, I believe that my question was redundant because, as per the comment from @Biscuits, I don't need to do any additional transformations.
I.e. my new orientation `qs'` will be given by `qs' = qs * qr`
The way I am thinking of it now (and I hope that this is correct) is that the orientation quaternion `qs` already describes the rotation required to move from the world frame to the sensor frame, so the further rotation `qr` can just be applied directly to that. @Biscuits if you put this in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in my earlier comment, this is actually simpler than you may think.  Remember, $qs$ and $qr$ are fundamentally [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), where the former represents *orientation* (in reference to the outside world) and the latter represents *rotation* (irrespective of any reference coordinate system).

You're right in saying that you don't need to do any additional transformations and that your new orientation $qs'$ will be given by:

$qs' = qs \times qr$

where;

- $qs$ is the previous [position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_(vector)), and
- $qr$ is a single rotation by a given [angle $\theta$ about a fixed axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation) (obtained from the gyroscope).

**Example**

Let's presume a simple analogy with straight line displacement;

$\delta s = v \times \delta t$

Given an initial position $s$, it can be said that moving at a velocity $v$ for a period of time $t$ sees us ending up at a final position $s'$:

$s' = s + \delta s$

Similarly, presume *angular* displacement (rotation in one axis);

$\delta \theta = \omega \times \delta t$

Given an initial *angular* position $\theta$, it can be said that moving at an *angular* velocity $\omega$ for a period of time $t$ sees us ending up at a final *angular* position $\theta'$:

$\theta' = \theta + \delta \theta$

Now, presume angular displacement in *three-dimensional space* (rotation in three axes) that, according to [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem), is *equivalent* to a single rotation by a given angle $\theta$ about a fixed axis $\hat \omega$;

$qr_w = \cos \dfrac{\theta}{2}$

$qr_x = \omega_x \times \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}$

$qr_y = \omega_y \times \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}$

$qr_z = \omega_z \times \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}$

Given initial *three-dimensional* angular positions (orientation) $qs$, it can be said that moving at angular velocities $\omega_x$, $\omega_y$ and $\omega_z$ for a period of time $t$ sees us ending up at final *three-dimensional* angular positions (orientation) $qs'$:

$qs' = qs \times qr$

Therefore, as straight line displacement $\delta s$ can be accumulated to track the position along a straight line $s$, so can angular displacements about three axes (or, rather, their single *equivalent* angular displacement about the Euler axis $qr$) be accumulated to track angular position in three-dimensional space (orientation) $qs$.

Comment: For reference, you can look at [this](https://github.com/tswanepoel/pilotgadgetry/blob/master/Biscuits.Flight/Ahrs.cs) C# implementation for an [AHRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_and_heading_reference_system).  Specifically pay attention to how `GroundOrientation` is continually calculated by applying `Rotation`.

Comment: In your example, you are using the relative angular velocities (wx, wy, wz) in the 3 axes to scale the vector part of the quaternion - is that correct?
But if you are considering three separate rotations (and rotation axes) then what rotation does theta relate to?
I am slightly confused about this additional information but this may just require more study on my part.